# sed - Remove all of a line except matching pattern

Tags: regex, sed

I am working at trying to parse out hashtags from a file. For instance:

```
Some text here #Foo Some other text here....
```

I would like the output to be:

```
#Foo
```

The text before and after the # can change and I'm trying to apply this to multiple lines of the file. Every line will have a # in it as I already grep'd the file for hashtags.

Basically I'm trying to create a list of the hashtags that are contained in a file. If there is also a way to remove duplicated tags from the resulting output that would be a bonus.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use eg `grep -o -E '#\S+' myfile.txt`

Comment: Haha! I was just experimenting with that! The main reason I guess that would not work is I want to change the file in place, but I didnt mention that in the initial question and I actually might be able to work around that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/^[^#]*(#[^[:blank:]]*).*/\1/'
```

- `^[^#]*` matches the portion before first `#`
- `(#[^[:blank:]]*)` matches the `#` followed by any number of non-space/tab characters, and put the match in captured group 1
- `.*` matches the rest
- In the replacement, the captured group `\1` is used

**Example:**

```
% sed -E 's/^[^#]*(#[^[:blank:]]*).*/\1/' <<<'Some text here #Foo Some other text here'
#Foo
```

Comment: This answer does the exact same thing as the 'grep' command answer but uses 'sed' to get the job done so I marked it as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -o '#[^ ]*' file
```

Comment: Thumbs up for using 'grep' as this seems more like the proper way to get this done.